# Create ERD for a mySQL DB by selecting only some of the main tables

Tags: mysql, reverse-engineering, erd, workbench

I need to create an ERD for our DB system. As it happens, there are lots and lots of tables, and no one really understands much of it. What's more, the same DB has tables for different applications, so not all tables are relevant to my application. I need an ERD for only my application's tables.

I tried creating ERD from MySQL workbench. It allows me to select a subset of the tables to put on an ERD, but that's the problem: I don't know which tables to select ( One of the reasons to build the diagram in the first place :-)  ).

What I do know are some of the 'main' tables involved. What I'm looking for is this: I tell the tool some 5-10 of these main tables I'm interested in, and the tool automatically picks up all the tables that are linked to these tables, and creates the ERD for them.

Any pointers?

Otherwise, I'll have to live with building my list of tables manaully, one by one...

Answer (score 0):

http://www.fabforce.net/ has a nice tool called DBDesigner, I have used this in the past for some reverse engineering on a datamodel.

Comment: Thanks peter. I looked at it: DBDesigner is now refering users to MySQL Workbench, which is the one I'm using...